# Phantom-Cassandra Insert/update behaviour

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I am trying to link up two tables with the same data like over here:
http://outworkers.com/blog/post/a-series-on-cassandra-part-1-getting-rid-of-the-sql-mentality

My second table contains the data I want to query by for example:

```
foo (
  id text,
  time timestamp,
  a int,
  b int,
  c int,
  d int,
  PRIMARY KEY (time, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC, id ASC)
```

So here I want to query by timestamp or id.
Now a,b,c,d are items which should be unique, i.e., the PRIMARY KEY(a, b, c, d). For this I create the first table:

```
bar (
  id text,
  time timestamp,
  a int,
  b int,
  c int,
  d int,
  PRIMARY KEY (a, b, c, d)
)
```

The thing is, during the insert, id and time might change but a, b, c, d will remain the same.
Now, I was hoping to do something along the lines of that consistency thing mentioned in the blog post. The problem I am facing is that if I try to insert an item with the same `(a, b, c, d)`, bar happily updates the corresponding row but foo creates a new entry. How would I go about deleting the older entry in foo or updating foo like bar???

Answer (score 2):

According to [Cassandra documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/update_r.html):

> UPDATE cannot update the values of a row's primary key fields

And here is example for phantom delete query: https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/wiki/Querying#delete-queries